# Python PyInquirer - action after input

Tags: python

I would like to have an action after given certain output from PyInquirer. The idea is to have a menu to select certain items. When choosing a item, it should launch a script or another action. In this example i've used print("okay") as a example.

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals

from PyInquirer import style_from_dict, Token, prompt, Separator
from pprint import pprint
import os


style = style_from_dict({
    Token.Separator: '#cc5454',
    Token.QuestionMark: '#673ab7 bold',
    Token.Selected: '#cc5454',  # default
    Token.Pointer: '#673ab7 bold',
    Token.Instruction: '',  # default
    Token.Answer: '#f44336 bold',
    Token.Question: '',
})


questions = [
    {
        'type': 'checkbox',
        'message': 'Select a VIP build',
        'name': 'F5 configuration build',
        'choices': [
            Separator('= VIPS ='),
            {
                'name': 'Nieuwe HTTP VIP'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Nieuwe HTTPS VIP'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Niewe VIP'
            },
            Separator('= Pools ='),
            {
                'name': 'Nieuwe Pool'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Bestaande pool'
            },
            Separator('= Pool member ='),
            {
                'name': 'Nieuwe Pool Members'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Bestaande Pool Members'
            },
        ],
        'validate': lambda answer: 'You must choose atleast one option.' \
            if len(answer) == 0 else True
    }
]

answers = prompt(questions, style=style)
pprint(answers)
if answers == ("{'F5 configuration build': ['Nieuwe HTTP VIP']}"):
    print("okay")
```

So the

```
if answers == ("{'F5 configuration build': ['Nieuwe HTTP VIP']}"):
    print("okay")
```

Should print okay after choosing the first choice, but it doesn't happend.

Any advice would be welcome!

Edit *Spelling*

Comment: What does `answers` contain ? (It seems your checking the output). It seems the only issue in your code is that your `if` statement does evaluate to `True` ...  Please keep your question short! Given the contents of `answers` (you can post that), and the `if` statement,  you can ommit/remove all the code above.

Comment: Hi,

The answers = prompt(questions, style=style) will give as result: "{'F5 configuration build': ['Nieuwe HTTP VIP']}".

So,if that statement of answers is true, it should print okay. But it doesn't do that.

Comment: Did you look for examples in the documentation of the library you are using (PyInquirer) ? What you are trying to do should be a basic task !

Comment: It might be that `answers` is not actually a string (type `str`) - when you print it, it will be converted to a string, but testing for equality will not yield `True` in such a case.
You can do `print(type(answers))` to examine the type.

Comment: It response on F5 configuration build, everything after that it doesn't read. I think the libary PyInquirer modifies the string in to something we can not see.

Might be a action worthwhile to debug this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The name should be a value that is easier to evaluate, for example only "F5" the user will not see it.

It is a type of dict data, you must access it through the index.

```
answers = prompt(questions, style=style)
pprint(answers)
if answers.get('F5', []) == ['Nieuwe HTTP VIP']:
    print("okay")
```